# Moving average over time series

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, moving-average

I need help to get the mean of the variables E, N and Z, by 7 days per ID.

The data frame is 290512 x 5 which `head` looks like the following:

```
ID  Date        E           N       Z
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.827
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.828
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.827
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.828
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.828
1   2012-03-16  676620.5    4090699 26.828
```

Statments:

1. `ID <- 1:21`;
2. Date from 2012-03-16 to 2016-12-31, without continuity (no NA's);
3. n. obs of E = N = Z;
4. The #obs can be different for each point.

E.g., If I get E for ID = 5, I also get N and Z on this obsertavion, but at the same time I cannot get an obs to ID = 12. This data is from soil deformation and over the soil mass are settled some total station targets.

My solution so far is

```
df_dm <- df %>%
group_by(ID, Date) %>%
summarise(E_dm = mean(E),
          N_dm = mean(N),
          Z_dm = mean(Z))
```

to get the daily means and then,

```
m <- 7
df_wm <- sapply(df_dm, function(x) rollapply( x, width = m, by = m, align = "left", FUN = mean))
```

which comes from an answer to a moving average question.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data only has a single date. Do you want to calculate the mean by separate windows of 7 days (for example, by week)? If so, you can create a new column, `Week` with a unique identifier for each week, and use that to group by rather than `Date`.

Alternatively, you might want to take a rolling average. Look to the function `rollmean` in the `zoo` package. For example:

```
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2004, rep(1:4, 4:1), sample(1:28, 10), sep = "-"))
x <- zoo(rnorm(12), x.Date)

rollmean(x, 3)

 2004-01-17  2004-01-23  2004-01-26  2004-02-07  2004-02-18  2004-02-24  2004-03-20  2004-03-27 
 0.60112115  0.80818151  0.64316904  0.06831874 -0.03085218 -0.05787362  0.34177806 -0.40876877
```

Comment: It's the `head` of the data frame. I'll take a look to the `rollmean` function.